# How to call a model method immediately after my application loads in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization

How do I call a models method just after my application loads. This sets up some of the business rules in my application and I want to run this method every time my server is restarted or changes have been made to my production.

What would be the best way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Use the [after_initialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Configuration.html#M002546) callback.

Unlike before/after filters, it's executed only once after the bootstrap. Here's a [short tutorial](http://toolmantim.com/articles/environments_and_the_rails_initialisation_process).

Answer (score 0):

You can put in a `before_filter` into the ApplicationController.

`before_filter :load_business_rules`

That will call the `load_business_rules` method each time.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Was wondeing, Would it be a good idea to add in the config.after_initialize to call the method?

Comment: It works. Though would still like to know whats the "Rails Way" on doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to do this in your environment file instead of as a before_filter. The reason being a before_filter will create a performance hit as the method is ran before every action on your site. What you could do instead is simply call it with an initializer or if you need to store those business rules as a static object you could declare it as a constant in your environment:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  ...
end

BUSINESS_RULES = load_business_rules
```

It really depends on what that method does. If you're just storing a bunch of constants in a static object you could just create a simple class and drop it in your models directory.

For example on an e-commerce site I recently built I created a Store model:

```
class Store
  # Constants
  MAX_QUANTITY = 10
  SALES_TAX_RATE = 0.081
  SALES_TAX_STATES = ["AZ","Arizona"]
  SHIPPING_METHODS = {"Standard" => "standard", "2nd Day  (add $18)" => "2nd day"}
  SHIPPING_COSTS = {"standard" => 0, "2nd day" => 18}
  SHIPPING_MINIMUM = 6
  SHIPPING_RATES = [[25,6],[50,8],[70,9],[100,11],[150,13],[200,15],[200,18]]
  ...
end
```

Then in my controllers, views, or models I could reference these constants easily just by:

```
Store::MAX_QUANTITY
```

I hope that helps!